# Show graph for data over 10 billions lines

Tags: excel, graph, bigdata

I have a 40G data file containing over 10 billions line.

Each line contains 2 columns, separate by comma, both columns are of the type 'float' and the first columns increases each row.

I want to show this data in a file, and I've tried Excel, but it said too many lines and can't display all.

Is there any other tools that can handle large data and show a line graph of the data?

Comment: I would recommend checking out R. It's free and open-source and pretty easy to learn for something quick like this. Alternative could be Python with pandas and matplotlib.

Comment: Pretty sure you're not going to be able to plot 10billion actual points.  You'll have to decide how you want to summarize the data and then plot a summary.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not the right tool for files of that size. There is no prefect rule, but I usually move the data into a relational database if it is over 200,000 rows. In SQL you can perform the logic to create a smaller dataset that aggregates the data into a more manageable size.

If you cannot achieve an excel-worthy size, then you'll need to look into options like Tableau that can graph data in a relational database.